# work in one branch in SVN and commit to different branch

Tags: svn

In our team we have development branch where programmers can work and commit as they want, and a build branch where they commit only changes that they finished and are ready to build.
after finishing a build we create a tag.

To work they need to take the tag of the latest build, work on it, and commit to the dev branch along the way and to the build branch when they finish.

What is the correct way to do the commit? with SVN switch or with svn patch? (or there is a different way)

Comment: I think you should be porting changes instead (`svn merge`).

Answer (score -1):

svn switch (sw) — Update working copy to a different URL.

svn patch — Apply changes represented in a unidiff patch to the working copy.

svn patch reports a status line for patched file or directory using letter codes, very similar to the way that svn update provides notification. The letter codes have the following meanings:

A

```
Added
```

D

```
Deleted
```

C

```
Conflicted
```

G

```
Merged
```

U

```
Updated
```

Changes applied with an offset or fuzz are reported on lines starting with the '>' symbol. You should review such changes carefully.